# Make scrollbar always visible on iOS 15 doesn't work

Tags: css, ios

I'm trying to make the scrollbar of a div (not the entire body) always visible, it works everywhere except on Safari & Chrome on iOS.
It looks like ::-webkit-scrollbar doesn't work on iOS.

The CSS that I've tried, that works everywhere but on iOS:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
   width: 20px;
   background: red;
}
```

Do you know any workaround to make it work? Do you know why iOS doesn't support that?

Thanks!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar you can refer here

Comment: I've already been there, I saw it should be supported.

However, it doesn't work, like the example CSS I attached.

Comment: According to caniuse it is not really supported on IOS Safari see https://caniuse.com/?search=%3A%3A-webkit-scrollbar

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```css
html,
html > * {
    -moz-overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical;
         overflow-y: scroll;
}
body::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 20px;
    background: red;
}
```

Hope this works.

Comment: It doesn't work :(

Comment: Then it might be a iOS-side issue... By the way the macOS Safari is also Apple WebKit, maybe try it to check?